# Jquery .submit() callback to close loading modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, callback

i have my controller that returns a PDF (i'm using Framework Rotativa PDF). Using ajax is not possible to make my request. So, i need a callback to close my loading modal after processing the request and returned because the same request can be long.

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult DownloadViewPDF()
{
   var model = new GeneratePDFModel();
   //Code to get content
   return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("GeneratePDF", model){FileName = "TestViewAsPdf.pdf"}
}
```

MY FORM

```
<form id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Content("/PDF/DownloadViewPDF/")">
   <input type="text" name="myparameter" />
</form>

<button id="sendForm" value="OK"></button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#sendForm').on('click', function () {
    $('#loadingModal').modal('show');
    $('#myform').submit();
    //after i need close this modal
});
```

Comment: Doesn't submitting the form cause the page to unload anyway, in favor of the new request?

Comment: @David It's just an example that put it here. The code architecture is very similar. I'm looking for some way to identify when the finished form to be sent to close my modal, because the page does not reload.

Comment: Have you tried using: `$('#myform').on('submit', function(){/* close modal here */})` before registering the `click` event-listener for the `sendForm` button?

Comment: @leo.fcx yes, but it closes as soon as the form is sent. This request may take a while, so I need to close the loading only when the request to return success or completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and chain these events together so one event fires off the next if AJAX is out of the question.

```
$( "#sendForm" ).click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#myform').submit();
});

$("#myform").submit(function( event ) {
  //close dialog here
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work :/ there is a callback to .submit()?